# Объединить метки [маршрутизация] и [routing]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [маршрутизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [routing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routing) в сторону русскоязычной. Ну и по традиции, разумеется, добавить соответствующее описание.

Comment: А если я не согласен, что это одно и то же?

Comment: @Qwertiy то можно голосовать "против", и предоставить ответ, обосновывающий Вашу точку зрения. Но возможно уже поздно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метки объединены. Основной выбрана [маршрутизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).